# APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating emergency threads for unassigned pending tasks

Tags: hibernate, c3p0

basically my code consumes some files from some other product and it corrects file in a single thread.after correction 2000 files i get an exception

> async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@4dc94cb -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating emergency threads for unassigned pending tasks!
>   FINEST|1396/0|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:10:01|[INFO] util.ServiceProcessOutputReceiver  for job id :: [ 3448 ] and taskId :: [ 00000165c894c1e97bf8db8900c000a800040039 ]
>   FINEST|1396/0|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:10:36|[INFO] 
>   FINEST|1396/0|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:11:29|[INFO] util.UploadFileUtil File uploading completed, removing corrected files from workspace.
>   FINEST|1396/0|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:12:34|[INFO] util.UploadFileUtil Deleted  with return value :: true
>   INFO|1396/0|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:17:08|Missing wrapper ping within timeout of 120000
>   WARNING|1396/0|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:19:48|ping between java application and wrapper timed out. if this this is due to server overload consider increasing wrapper.ping.timeout
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:20:59|restart process due to default exit code rule
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:21:10|restart internal RUNNING
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:21:29|stopping process with pid/timeout 1396 45000
>   INFO|1396/0|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:24:26|controller close session
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:33:53|Error in Process.waitFor OS result #258 The wait operation timed out.
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:34:08|process did not stop after 45000 sec. -> hard kill
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:38:04|process exit code: 999
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:38:51|working dir C:\Program Files\Baton Content Corrector\database
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:39:12|Warning: WaitForInputIdle returned 258
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:39:13|started process with pid 3540
>   WARNING|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:39:27|startup of java application timed out. if this is due to server overload consider increasing wrapper.startup.timeout
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:39:34|restart process due to default exit code rule
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:39:34|restart internal RUNNING
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:39:34|stopping process with pid/timeout 3540 45000
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:40:22|Error in Process.waitFor OS result #258 The wait operation timed out.
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:40:25|process did not stop after 45000 sec. -> hard kill
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:41:36|process exit code: 999
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:42:27|working dir C:\Program Files\Baton Content Corrector\database
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:42:37|Warning: WaitForInputIdle returned 258
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:42:38|started process with pid 8064
>   WARNING|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:42:57|startup of java application timed out. if this is due to server overload consider increasing wrapper.startup.timeout
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:42:58|restart process due to default exit code rule
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:42:58|restart internal RUNNING
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:42:58|stopping process with pid/timeout 8064 45000
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:43:49|Error in Process.waitFor OS result #258 The wait operation timed out.
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:43:52|process did not stop after 45000 sec. -> hard kill
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:45:37|process exit code: 999
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:46:19|working dir C:\Program Files\Baton Content Corrector\database
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:46:52|Warning: WaitForInputIdle returned 258
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:46:53|started process with pid 7276
>   WARNING|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:47:07|startup of java application timed out. if this is due to server overload consider increasing wrapper.startup.timeout
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:47:09|restart process due to default exit code rule
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:47:09|restart internal RUNNING
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:47:09|stopping process with pid/timeout 7276 45000
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:47:54|Error in Process.waitFor OS result #258 The wait operation timed out.
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:47:54|process did not stop after 45000 sec. -> hard kill
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:48:39|process exit code: 999
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:49:01|working dir C:\Program Files\Baton Content Corrector\database
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:49:06|Warning: WaitForInputIdle returned 258
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:49:07|started process with pid 2632
>   WARNING|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:49:33|startup of java application timed out. if this is due to server overload consider increasing wrapper.startup.timeout
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:49:49|restart process due to default exit code rule
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:49:49|restart internal RUNNING
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:49:49|stopping process with pid/timeout 2632 45000
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:50:34|Error in Process.waitFor OS result #258 The wait operation timed out.
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:50:34|process did not stop after 45000 sec. -> hard kill
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:51:24|process exit code: 999
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:51:56|working dir C:\Program Files\Baton Content Corrector\database
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:52:07|Warning: WaitForInputIdle returned 258
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:52:10|started process with pid 5852
>   WARNING|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:52:27|startup of java application timed out. if this is due to server overload consider increasing wrapper.startup.timeout
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:52:27|restart process due to default exit code rule
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:52:27|restart internal RUNNING
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:52:27|stopping process with pid/timeout 5852 45000
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:53:12|Error in Process.waitFor OS result #258 The wait operation timed out.
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:53:13|process did not stop after 45000 sec. -> hard kill
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:54:42|process exit code: 999
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:55:50|working dir C:\Program Files\Baton Content Corrector\database
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:56:10|Warning: WaitForInputIdle returned 258
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:56:11|started process with pid 6448
>   WARNING|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:56:21|startup of java application timed out. if this is due to server overload consider increasing wrapper.startup.timeout
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:56:22|restart process due to default exit code rule
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:56:22|restart internal RUNNING
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:56:22|stopping process with pid/timeout 6448 45000
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:57:07|Error in Process.waitFor OS result #258 The wait operation timed out.
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:57:07|process did not stop after 45000 sec. -> hard kill
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:58:00|process exit code: 999
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:58:20|working dir C:\Program Files\Baton Content Corrector\database
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:58:23|Warning: WaitForInputIdle returned 258
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:58:23|started process with pid 5496
>   WARNING|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:58:51|startup of java application timed out. if this is due to server overload consider increasing wrapper.startup.timeout
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:58:51|restart process due to default exit code rule
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:58:51|restart internal RUNNING
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:58:51|stopping process with pid/timeout 5496 45000
>   INFO|5496/7|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:01|java.io.IOException: The handle is invalid
>   INFO|5496/7|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:01|    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
>   INFO|5496/7|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:01|    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>   INFO|5496/7|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:01|    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
>   INFO|5496/7|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:01|    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>   INFO|5496/7|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:01|    at org.rzo.yajsw.io.TeeInputStream$Source.run(TeeInputStream.java:221)
>   INFO|5496/7|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:01|    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   INFO|5496/7|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:01|    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   INFO|5496/7|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:01|    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   INFO|5496/7|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:07|[INFO] StandardFileSystemManager - Using "C:\Windows\TEMP\vfs_cache" as temporary files store.
>   INFO|5496/7|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:10|Unable to classify GarbageCollectorMXBean [G1 Young Generation]
>   INFO|5496/7|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:10|Unable to classify GarbageCollectorMXBean [G1 Old Generation]
>   INFO|5496/7|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:10|!! WARNING !! Windows JDK7 should set -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true (see java bug 7179799 )
>   INFO|5496/7|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:12|wrapper manager received stop command
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:13|controller close session
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:13|process exit code: 0
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:33|working dir C:\Program Files\Baton Content Corrector\database
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:36|Warning: WaitForInputIdle returned 258
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:36|started process with pid 8728
>   INFO|8728/8|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:36|java.io.IOException: The handle is invalid
>   INFO|8728/8|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:36|!! WARNING !! Windows JDK7 should set -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true (see java bug 7179799 )
>   INFO|8728/8|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:36|    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
>   INFO|8728/8|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:36|wrapper manager received stop command
>   INFO|8728/8|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:36|    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>   INFO|8728/8|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:36|    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
>   INFO|8728/8|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:36|    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
>   INFO|8728/8|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:36|    at org.rzo.yajsw.io.TeeInputStream$Source.run(TeeInputStream.java:221)
>   INFO|8728/8|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:36|    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   INFO|8728/8|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:36|    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   INFO|8728/8|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:36|    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   INFO|8728/8|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:36|[INFO] StandardFileSystemManager - Using "C:\Windows\TEMP\vfs_cache" as temporary files store.
>   INFO|8728/8|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:36|Unable to classify GarbageCollectorMXBean [G1 Young Generation]
>   INFO|8728/8|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:36|Unable to classify GarbageCollectorMXBean [G1 Old Generation]
>   INFO|8728/8|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:36|2018-09-12 14:59:35.518:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-7.x.y-SNAPSHOT
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:36|restart process due to default exit code rule
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:36|shutdown wrapper due to exit code rule
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:36|process not in state RUNNING -> Delaying stop
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:36|shutdown wrapper due to exit code rule
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:36|calling onStop
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:36|Win service stop - timeout: 30000
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:36|Win service wrapper.control -> stopping application
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:36|process not in state RUNNING -> Delaying stop
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:36|Win service stop - after shutdown
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:36|Win service stop - before notify
>   INFO|wrapper|Service yajsw|18-09-12 14:59:36|Win service terminated

I have read many articles and many of them has suggested to keep hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period less than c3p0 timeout which also makes sense.

Also i guess the deadlock may be due to caching of statements that have been set to 50 and keeping them to 0 might resolve the deadlock situation

Here is my c3p0 configuration

```
<property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">75</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
```

Please guide!!

Comment: there's lots missing from your log. The active and pending tasks and pool thread stack traces should be printed. without this information, it's hard to say much about your `APPARENT DEADLOCK`. see https://github.com/swaldman/mchange-commons-java/blob/615c55e14ff0f3034d2780b6f72def46c56c1f21/src/main/java/com/mchange/v2/async/ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java#L791-L807

Comment: i have provided the full stack trace.there is no further information in logs